# Should you layer Greek yoghurt on porridge oats or mix it in with the porridge oats?

Tags: yogurt, mixing, oats

I am experimenting with creating overnight oats with Greek yoghurt. However, I was not sure whether to layer the yoghurt on top of the oats with multiple layers of oats and yoghurt, or to mix in the yoghurt with the oats.

I was told by one person to layer the oats and yoghurt, but online tutorials seem to instruct you to mix the oats instead.

**Should I layer or mix my yoghurt with the oats?**

**Are there any benefits of choosing one method over the other?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point of overnight oats is to allow the oats time to hydrate slowly at a cool temperature, rather than cooking them in water. So it's best to have them well-mixed with the liquid they'll be absorbing. If you put them in (sufficiently thick) layers, it's likely that some of the oats will be less hydrated than others.